# Сортировка только отрицательных чисел в массиве

Tags: c++, c

Нужно отсортировать только отрицательные числа в массиве. Положение элементов в массиве не менять.

Пример:
Исходный массив:

-98 65 -87 56 65 -65 837 -24

Вывод:

-24 65 -65 56 65 -87 837 -98

Но мой алгоритм работает не так верно как хотелось бы...

Он сортирует лишь некоторые отрицательные числа, а нужно чтобы было четко по убыванию как в примере.

```
//first version of 9.1 - using just a bubble sort

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define N 10

void negsort(int *array, int size);            // a bubble sort for negatives
void swap(int *element1, int *element2);     // swap elements(for sorting)
void enter(int *array, int size);           // entering array
void arintf(int *array, int size);     // printing array
int setsize(int size);                    // seting the size


void swapbts(int *element1, int *element2){

     int exchanger = 0;

     if(*element1 < *element2 /*&& *element1 < 0*/){
     exchanger = *element1;
     *element1 = *element2;
     *element2 = exchanger;
     }
}

void negsort(int *array, int size){

    int *foward, *back, dummy = 1, *negative;

    for(back = &array[size]; back >= array; back--){
       for(foward = array; foward < back; foward++){
       if(*foward >= 0){
          dummy++;
       }

       if(*foward < 0) negative = foward;

       else if(*negative < 0 && dummy >= 1){
        if(*(negative + dummy) < 0){
        swapbts(negative, negative + dummy);
        dummy = 1;
                }
       }
     }
    }

   // return array;
}
```

Comment: И что именно вас не устраивает?

Comment: этот алгоритм лишь частично сортирует, посмотрите функцию negsort

Comment: Вот и напишите в тексте вопроса, все что вы ожидали и что получили. [Почитайте в help-е](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Исправил, мимнимизировал код

Comment: Вопрос-то был в том, какие числа вы вводили, какие получили, и какие хотели получить.

Comment: Всмысле? Я же указал, чего я ожидал, я ожидал отсортированные по убыванию только отрицательные числа, а такой сортировки у меня не получается...

Comment: Странный алгоритм. Почему вы решили, что он будет правильно сортировать? Мне кажется, что в вашем (довольно экзотическом случае) проще всего выбрать что-то известное и подходящее по сути задачи. Например, сортировку с поиском максимума. Ищете максимум среди отрицательных и обмениваете его с первым отрицательным элементом. Повторяете для остатка массива.

Comment: Во-первых, когда отвечаете на чей-то комментарий, лучше начинайте свой ответ с `@username`. Иначе мы не получаем уведомлений и скорее всего не ответим. Вы же получаете уведомления всегда, потому что комментарии - под вашим вопросом.

Comment: *"Всмысле? Я же указал, чего я ожидал"* Вы написали, что вы ожидали, да. А avp попросил написать, какой вывод вы получили. Этого в вопросе нет. *"Чтобы я без вас делал? Вот что, скажите?"* А что вам не нравится в комментарии выше? Если вежливо объяснить, что вам не понятно или вас не устраивает, больше шанс получить нормальную помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гов.. Ой то есть такой себе код.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <random>

void swap(int *xp, int *yp)
{
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}

template<int size>
void weirdSort(int (&arr)[size]){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            if(arr[i]<0 && arr[j] <0){
                 if(arr[i] < arr[j])
                     swap(&arr[i],&arr[j]);
            }
}


int main()
{
    int array[100]{0};
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(-1000,1000);
    for(int i =0 ; i < 100; ++i){
        array[i] = distribution(generator);
    }

    weirdSort(array);

}
```

Comment: На подобных данных (сортируется примерно половина) было бы хорошо подсчитывать количество `swap` при каждом прохождении внутреннего цикла и заканчивать сортировку, если `swap`-ов не было

Comment: Пятикратная вложенность)))) Тут плачет один разработчик ядра Linux)))

Comment: @Ljil, вы ещё не видели, что пишется и как на C# со всеми этими foreach(ами), которые каждую итерацию цикла вызывают несколько методов (чтобы произошла итерация, за кулисами вызываются методы), всякие Linq запросы километровые и т.д. Тут ещё божественно быстрый код.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем, я смог все-таки сам решить эту задачу.

```
//first version of 9.1 - using just a bubble sort 

#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 

#define N 10 

void negsort(int *array, int size); // a bubble sort for negatives 
void swap(int *element1, int *element2); // swap elements(for sorting) 
void enter(int *array, int size); // entering array 
void arintf(int *array, int size); // printing array 
int setsize(int size); // seting the size 

int main(){ 

int a[N] /*= {-98, 65, -87, 35, -76, -65, -45, 56, 76, -34}*/, n = N; 

clrscr(); 

n = setsize(n); 

enter(a, n); 

negsort(a, n); 

arintf(a, n); 

getch(); 
return 0; 
} 

void enter(int *array, int size){ 
int *el_scan; 

printf("Enter elements of your array:\n"); 

for(el_scan = array; el_scan < &array[size]; el_scan++){ 
printf("a[%d] = ", (el_scan - array) + 1); 
scanf("%d", el_scan); 
} 
} 

void arintf(int *array, int size){ 
int *el_print; 

printf("Modified array:\n"); 

for(el_print = array; el_print < &array[size]; el_print++){ 
printf("%d ", *el_print); 
} 
} 

void swapbts(int *element1, int *element2){ 

int exchanger = 0; 

if(*element1 < *element2 /*&& *element1 < 0*/){ 
exchanger = *element1; 
*element1 = *element2; 
*element2 = exchanger; 
} 
} 

void negsort(int *array, int size){ 

int *foward, *back, dummy = 0, *negative, *secneg; 

for(back = &array[size]; back >= array; back--){ 
for(foward = array; foward < back; foward++){ 
if (*foward < 0) negative = foward; 

else if(*foward > 0){ 
dummy = 0; 
dummy++; 
} 

if(*(foward + dummy) < 0) secneg = foward + dummy; 

swapbts(negative, secneg); 
} 
} 

// return array; 
} 

int setsize(int size){ 

printf("Enter the size of array(max = 10): "); 
scanf("%d", &size); 

if(size > N){ 
printf("You entered size that bigger than max. Setting to max.\n"); 
size = N; 
} 
else if(size <= 1){ 
printf("We cannot sort a array with only one element. Setting to 2.\n"); 
size = 2; 
} 
return(size); 
}
```